# Cloth simulation is tearing during the character animation

Tags: animation, add-on, cloth-simulation, clipping

I'm using Simply Cloth Pro add-on and trying to practice with cloth simulation. I took Mixamo animated characted and trying to dress him up. But when his leg is moving up the pants are tearing on his knees. What should I do to avoid this?

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IHR9Y9KwK4eGqt7GntT_0EzTFbUI92Do/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

[image]

[image]